# What does Rabboni really mean?

Tags: hebrew, aramaic, etymology

I’ve read it said from Albert Pike that Rabboni isn’t Aramaic, but it is derived from the Hebrew “RB BNI”, meaning master builder or master of builders in Hebrew. Is this true?

Mark 10:51

> And Jesus answering him says, "What do you desire I should do to you?" And the blind man said to Him, "**Rabboni**, that I may receive sight."

John 20:16

> Jesus says to her, "Mary." Having turned around, she says to Him in Hebrew, "**Rabboni**," that is to say, "Teacher."

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: also... it helps if you provide the scripture that you refer to. I don't see a reference to Aramaic in the Greek of John 20:16, which is literally "Jesus saith to her, `Mary!' having turned, she saith to him, `Rabbouni;' that is to say, `Teacher.' (YLT)

Answer (score 4):

The operative word here is  ῥαββουνί (rhabbouni) and, as the OP has listed, occurs just twice in the NT.

In John 20:16 it is declared to be a Hebrew word meaning, "teacher".

BDAG claims it is a "heightened form of רב ... **my lord, my master**".

Thayer suggests something similar: "*a title of honor and reverence by which Jesus is addressed; as interpreted by John, equivalent to διδάσκαλος*" [= teacher]

Thus, it appears to be a title of respect.  The word may have originated in Aramaic (this cannot be confirmed) and is of uncertain origin; but in any case, by the time of its inclusion in Hebrew in the NT, it had become a title of respect meaning (according the inspired word of John 20:16), "teacher".

**APPENDIX - Text of John 20:16**

The Greek text of John 20:16 is disputed.

According to UBS5/NA28, W&H, Souter, THGNT, NIVGNT, SBL, etc, the text of John 20:16 is:

> λέγει αὐτῇ Ἰησοῦς Μαριάμ. στραφεῖσα ἐκείνη λέγει αὐτῷ **Ἐβραϊστί**
> Ῥαββουνεί ὃ λέγεται Διδάσκαλε. = Jesus said to her, “Mary.” She turned
> and said to Him in **Hebrew**, “Rabboni!” (which means “Teacher”).

According to R&P/Byzantine text, Majority text, F35, TR, etc, the text of John 20:16 is:

> Λέγει αὐτῇ ὁ Ἰησοῦς, Μαρία. Στραφεῖσα ἐκείνη λέγει αὐτῷ, Ῥαββουνί― ὃ
> λέγεται, Διδάσκαλε. = Jesus said to her, “Mary.” She turned and said
> to Him, “Rabboni!” (which means “Teacher”).

Note that difference between the two is the "in Hebrew" in the first set of (early) texts which was deleted in the later Byzantine texts.

Comment: +1 especially for enlightening us about the textual variations.

Comment: So those translations that say rabboni is a Hebrew word are following an ancient text, but what about Aramaic? Is there a textual basis for that or are translators presuming it because of the fact that Aramaic was the language that Jesus and his disciples probably spoke?

Comment: @DanFefferman - the "Aramaic" often turns up in Elizabethan text but actually means (usually) "Hebrew".  It is thus a quirk of the KJV.  However, some modern versions perpetuate the "Aramaic" [presumably because they believe that Mary spoke Aramaic.  Thus, "Aramaic" is, in my judgement, an interpretive translation.

Comment: The reason for the question was that it was brought to me that Jesus was a master mason and Mary Magdalene was using Masonic language in that verse to mean “ master builder or master of builders. And I’ve been looking for a answer to that verse in question

Comment: @Betram - that is impossible because freemasonry only began in 1717.

Answer (score 1):

The word "Aramaic" is not in the Greek according to Young's Literal Translation, although translators sometimes add either "Aramaic" or "Hebrew."

> Jesus saith to her, 'Mary!' having turned, she saith to him,
> 'Rabbouni;' that is to say, 'Teacher.'

{However, see @Dottard's answer for textual variations.}

The "rab" part of the word original meant "great." But the issue is complicated by the fact that the only evidence for "rabboni" being used in Jesus' time is from the New Testament. Thus, some consider "rabboni" to be anachronistic. Later, "rabbi" came to mean teacher and "rabboni/rabbouni" master-teacher or great rabbi. According to a site devoted to understanding [the Jewishness of Jesus](https://www.ourancientpaths.org/post/2017/03/13/rabbi-rav-rabboni-rabban-and-sage):

> Rabboni means “my great Rabbi." Rabboni means “my great Rabbi”.  According to Jewish sources, Rabbi is greater than Rav {meaning literally great}; and Rabban is greater than Rabbi. The use of these words did not take
> place prior to the first century. For example, according to Jewish
> literature, Hillel The Elder was considered one of the greatest
> Rabbis of all time, but he bore no title of respect.

In terms of the etymology related to "builder," the Hebrew word for "build" is bānâ -בָּנָה (Strong's 1129). Written without vowels this could be related to the last two syllables of "rab-boni." It is also worth noting that "rabban" was a title of particularly high respect usually applied to the head of the Sanhedrin.

**Conclusion**: The Greek text does not seem to claim that the language in question was Aramaic. But the issue is not entirely clear partly because the historical sources are mostly from a later period than the time of Jesus. So the answer remains a matter of opinion. However, the idea that rabboni is related to the verb "to build" is plausible.

Comment: Thanks I corrected it.

Comment: The reason for the question was that it was brought to me that Jesus was a master mason and Mary Magdalene was using Masonic language in that verse to mean “ master builder or master of builders. And I’ve been looking for a answer to that verse in question